# Java amazon s3 with FakeS3 slow on putObject

Tags: java, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

For local environment I am using an improved version of [fakes3](https://github.com/jubos/fake-s3) (some ruby implementation).

In java I have this code:

```
private final AmazonS3Client client;
private final S3Configuration configuration;
private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
// code code...
final byte[] bytes = objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(object);
final InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
final ObjectMetadata metadata = createJsonMetadata();
metadata.setContentLength(bytes.length);
client.putObject(getBucket(), key, input, metadata);
```

What I am trying to do is to use this fakes3 (and it works) but the method `putObject` looks like it takes 3 seconds to execute and it's really annoying for our development environment.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer myself...

Amazon client is adding some `Expect: 100-continue` in header and according to [rfc2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html) the client is waiting for a response from server to proceed with the body.

Most servers don't implement this... I solved this in [my fork of FakeS3](https://github.com/alexmuntean/fake-s3) in commit [54876321f62ebb26d17cd731401784917e52d50d](https://github.com/alexmuntean/fake-s3/commit/54876321f62ebb26d17cd731401784917e52d50d)